# why does scala toString give type Any?

Tags: string, scala, type-conversion, tostring

I need to compose a String depending on the value of an Int - Scala is confusing me:

```
scala> val qqq: Int = -3
qqq: Int = -3

scala> qqq.toString
res17: String = -3

scala> if (qqq < 0)
     | qqq.toString
res19: Any = -3
```

what is going on there? Why is qqq.toString a string in the first but not the last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if `q >= 3` ? What *type* does `if` return then ?

e.g. if you write this:

```
if (qqq < 0) 
   "a"
else 
   "b"
```

you'll always get a `String` return type